# Discrepency in "rake preview" vs. "rake deploy"

Tags: octopress

I am having an issue where I can "rake preview" and view the site in a browser on localhost:4000 and everything seems to be displayed properly (fonts, styles, posts, text, asides, etc). However, when I "rake deploy" (which I have set to sync to Amazon S3), the site displays in such a way that it almost appears as if the CSS is missing, mis-configured, etc.

I have verified that the path referenced for the "/stylesheets/screen.css" exists in S3 and that the browser can open it. I have even done a diff on both screen.css and the main index.html from both the "preview" and the "deploy" and don't see any differences.

I have tried the following as possible resolutions:

- revert to a backup from prior to my most recent changes
- purge everything in the S3 bucket and re-deploy
- completely start over with a fresh installation of Octopress
- of course clear browser cache, try from behind different firewalls, test in different browsers and operating systems, etc.
- read through every question here tagged as 'octopress'

What may have triggered all of this was uncommenting the following line in sass/custom/_colors.scss:

$header-bg: #263347;

Before that the only other change was a "rake new_post" about a week ago. Un-doing either of those changes doesn't seem to help.

I'm at a complete and total loss as to what to try next. I'm sure this is something that will result in a face palm.

Here are links to some screenshots (I can't post inline because of insufficient reputation):

http://cdn.ihashacks.com/img/2013/06/preview.png
http://cdn.ihashacks.com/img/2013/06/deployed.png

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Is your blog hosted at `domain.com/blog`? If so, ensure that the site variables `url` and `root` in `_config.yml` are set properly.

If that doesn't solve it, can you provide a dump of the browser console? This will help to debug.