# Setup Octopress/Github pages with custom url

Tags: github-pages, octopress

I recently hosted my Octopress blog on Github Pages. Trouble came when I tried to consult it via my custom url, `http://example.org/`. CSS and JS did not load, as the browser console indicated.

I checked the page's source code and noticed the browser was told to look for the assets at the relative url (eg `<link href="/mypath/favicon.png" rel="icon">` for the favicon), which indeed does not work since there is nothing there.

I solved my issue by setting the `config_yml` "root" to `http://example.github.io/mypath`, thus going against the [octopress guidelines for deploying to a subdirectory](http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/subdir/) (which is the case with my Project Page use of Github Pages) I was following till then.

This and the fact that viewers of my blog, which'll arrive via `http://example.org/` will see `http://example.github.io/mypath` as soon as they click on any of the first page links, clearly indicates that my setup is wrong.

I have seriously spent hours on this one, read through [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17138615/discrepency-in-rake-preview-vs-rake-deploy) [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22498640/octopress-deploy-to-projectgh-pages-css-js) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25728635/octopress-not-loading-css), to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right setup is :

```
url: http://example.org

root: /
```

Comment: May I suggest improving the answer by adding how config.yml's "destination" field should be setup in this particular case? I currently have to set it as `public` for `rake preview` to work properly and change it to `public/mypath` before deploying otherwise I get a `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_stat - public/mypath/.`

Comment: Create the target directory `mkdir public/mypath/` before doing you rake preview.

Comment: isn't there a setup with which one does not have to change `config.yml` between every `preview` and `deploy`?!

Comment: Can you open a new question with this topic and finally approve my answer ?